# PHP Curl_multi_exec measure response time for each call

Tags: php, curl

Using curl_multi.
Is it possible to measure the response time for each descriptor(URL) or only the total time using a microtime? Using curl_getinfo for single thread, you can use curl_getinfo and get ['total_time'] from it. Have any trick for curl_multi?
I need multithreading like in the Apache AB.